# Disable Xbox Controller Input in Xamarin UWP App

Tags: input, uwp, focus, xamarin.uwp

My app is designed to be mostly interacted with using a mouse and keyboard. This is how the user should set up all the settings and initial conditions, but once they are ready they can click a button and the app will start sending UDP messages based off of a connected Xbox controller. At this point I don't want the Xbox controller to be able to affect the UI at all, I just want to read its state to construct these UDP messages. Right now, this isn't the case and the user may inadvertently press the "stop transmission" button when they weren't trying to. I can't find any documentation on how this might be achieved. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181197/how-to-prevent-xbox-controller-input-in-uwp-app), but no answer was given.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to come up with a work-around that seems to work pretty well. First, I made a hidden button:

```
<Button x:Name="nothingButton" IsVisible="false"/>
```

In the code-behind, I set its Unfocused handler to refocus on it whenever I don't want the Xbox controller to affect the UI (i.e. whenever my mainPageViewModel.IsTransmitting boolean is true):

```
nothingButton.Unfocused += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (mainPageViewModel.IsTransmitting)
            {
                nothingButton.Focus();
            }
        };
```

Lastly, once I want to enter this state of not affecting the UI, I just have to force focus on the hidden button once after setting IsTransmitting to true. It's pretty janky, but it works exactly how I want.

Comment: Please feel free mark yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Disable Xbox Controller Input in Xamarin UWP App

It looks known [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1495) in github, and msft has provide a workaround that edit [regedit](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1495#issuecomment-745586048), derive the comments, it looks the new reg key only available for windows 11.

*I joined the Windows Insider Program under the Release Preview Channel to get Windows 11 and the regedit change works.*

You may try to update to windows 11, and test above new reg key.